# I am looking into putting sound files onto an Arduino Nano without a microSD card

Tags: arduino-nano, speaker

I figured out how to install the sound onto the card from this site

https://github.com/charliegerard/dev-notes/blob/master/arduino/wavFilesWithoutSdCard.md

It says I need to use pin 11 on the Uno but would pin 11 on the nano work or not? I am getting these boards.

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0713XK923/ref=ox_sc_act_title_3?smid=A2WWHQ25ENKVJ1&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0713XK923)

Also, does anyone have good speaker suggestions, I'm going with these right now([https://www.amazon.com/CQRobot-JST-PH2-0-Interface-Electronic-Projects/dp/B0738NLFTG/ref=sr_1_6?dchild=1&keywords=speakers+arduino%5D%5C&qid=1607285501&sr=8-6](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0738NLFTG))

I'm not sure if I'm giving enough information so just tell me if I need to provide you with more information.

Comment: what's special about pin 11?

Comment: It just says to use pin 11 so I'm just going to use it.

Comment: what is your end use? ... why do you wish to use *wav files*?

Comment: So I am trying to play an audio file at the click of a button and I don't have to use .wav files it just says that in the thing. But the audio file is super short so I can put it on the arduino without a microsd card holder.

Answer (score 2):

Uno and Nano uses the same Atmel MCU, so pin 11 is the same on both.

And a for the speakers, Arduino CAN'T driver 8ohms load! You need a amplifier.

Comment: To add to the above for those wondering why pin 11: The OP is apparently using the [PCM library for Arduino](https://github.com/damellis/PCM/) which is hardcoded to use OC2A, that is timer 2 output compare A: https://github.com/damellis/PCM/blob/v1.0/PCM.c#L108   Which is Arduino Pin 11 for these 328P models.

Comment: Is there a way I could use another pin?